# Prove that $ \frac{|f'(z)|}{\Im (f(z))}\le \frac{1}{\Im(z)}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let , $f:U\to U$ be analytic , where $U$ is the upper-half plane. Then show that $\displaystyle \frac{|f'(z)|}{\Im (f(z))}\le \frac{1}{\Im(z)}$.

I want to use the result : If $f:\mathbb D\to \mathbb D$ is analytic $\displaystyle |f'(z)|\le \frac{1-|f(z)|^2}{1-|z|^2}$.

As , the function $g(z)=\displaystyle \frac{z-i}{z+i}$ maps the upper-half plane to the unit circle so , $\displaystyle g^{-1}(z)=i\frac{1+z}{1-z}$ maps the unit circle to the upper-half plane.

Now consider the function $F=g\circ f\circ g^{-1}:\mathbb D \to \mathbb D$ , where $\mathbb D$ is the open unit disc. Then ,  $\displaystyle |F'(z)|\le \frac{1-|F(z)|^2}{1-|z|^2}$. But from here I can't proceed and unable to shoe the given inequation.

Please help from this step. If there are any simplest way then tell me.

Comment: Compute $F'(z)$ via the chain rule, and fiddle around with the inequality. Do any difficulties turn up when you do that?

Comment: @ Daniel Fischer) Yes.. I got $F'=(gfg^{-1})'.(fg^{-1})'\frac{2i}{(1-z)^2}$. Then ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $g'(w) = \dfrac{2i}{(w+i)^2}$ and $(g^{-1})'(w) = \dfrac{2i}{(1-w)^2}$. Now let $u = g^{-1}(z)$ and $v = f(u)$. Then

$$F'(z) = g'(v)\cdot f'(u)\cdot (g^{-1})'(z) = \frac{2i}{(v+i)^2}\cdot f'(u)\cdot \frac{2i}{(1-z)^2} = \frac{-4 f'(u)}{(f(u)+i)^2(1-g(u))^2},$$

so the Schwarz-Pick lemma yields

$$\frac{4\lvert f'(u)\rvert}{\lvert f(u)+i\rvert^2\, \bigl\lvert 1- \frac{u-i}{u+i}\bigr\rvert^2} \leqslant \frac{1 - \bigl\lvert\frac{f(u)-i}{f(u)+i}\bigr\rvert^2}{1 - \bigl\lvert \frac{u-i}{u+i}\bigr\rvert^2}.$$

Cross-multiplication yields

$$\frac{4\lvert f'(u)\rvert}{\lvert f(u)+i\rvert^2 - \lvert f(u)-i\rvert^2} \leqslant \frac{\bigl\lvert 1-\frac{u-i}{u+i}\bigr\rvert^2}{1 - \bigl\lvert\frac{u-i}{u+i}\bigr\rvert^2} = \frac{\lvert (u+i) - (u-i)\rvert^2}{\lvert u+i\rvert^2 - \lvert u-i\rvert^2} = \frac{4}{\lvert u+i\rvert^2 - \lvert u-i\rvert^2}.$$

Now note that

$$\lvert w+i\rvert^2 - \lvert w-i\rvert^2 = -2i(w-\overline{w}) = 4\Im (w)$$

to conclude.